# Msiexec command prompt when running setup

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Seeing a strange problem with a few of my setups, when they are run a msiexec command prompt opens saying opening connection and it stays until the setup has been completed.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

[image]

Comment: Did u try running setup in log mode. Please run setup in log mode and check which custom action is creating window.

Comment: @SunilAgarwal I have tried this but I will again to see if I missed something. Thanks